# Function square-integrable

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, measure-theory, operator-theory

Let $f$ be an arbitrary function in $L^2(0,\infty)$ and consider the function

$$(g_f)(y) = \frac{1}{y-x_0} \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \left(\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2+1)}\right)^2 \ dx$$

where $x_0$ is an arbitrary point in $(0,\infty).$

I ask: Is the function $g_f$ ever a function in $L^2(0,\infty)?$

In other words, fix $x_0$ as above, does there exist a square-integrable $f$ such that $g_f$ is also in $L^2(0,\infty)$ [other than zero, of course]?

Comment: Check that the domain isn't just the zero function,  maybe?

Comment: I decided to change the question in that direction, as this may be the key to the solution. Thank you very much for your clever remarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Indeed set
$$
G_f(y) = (y-x_0) g_f(y)
       = \int_0^\infty f(x) \, \left(\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2+1)}\right)^{\!2} \, dx.
$$
It is easy to find linearly independent $f_1,f_2 \in L^2(0,\infty)$
such that each $G_{f_i}(y)$ is also in $L^2(0,\infty)$ and is differentiable
on $(0,\infty)$; for instance, $f_1,f_2$ can be characteristic functions of
different intervals.  Let $f$ be a nonzero linear combination 
$c_1 f_1 + c_2 f_2$ such that $G_f(x_0) = 0$.  Then $g_f \in L^2(0,\infty)$.

Comment: That looks like a much harder question.  What's the context?